# How can I hide Redshift schemas for a user who doesn't have access to them?

Tags: powerbi, amazon-redshift, schema, dbeaver

Looking for a way to hide Redshift schemas in SQL client that the user does not have access to.

I am using a Redshift cluster that has a few databases and multiple schemas under each of those. In one of the db, I have created a schema named 'analytics' that has several views pointing to tables present in other schemas but in the same database. I have a user named 'a_user' created that has SELECT access to the views in schema 'analytics' and 'USAGE ON SCHEMA' access to a few schemas where the tables belong to. When using an SQL client to connect to the Redshift db, I see all of the schemas even though the user 'a_user' does not have any read access to those schemas. I want the user to see only the 'analytics' schema. I want to know if there's a way to hide those schemas for which the user does not have access to. This user is created for business reporting and I do not want the end user to see any unnecessary details. Have tried this with PowerBI and I can see all the schemas there as well, so looks like all the tools will show up all schemas. Have read a lot of blogs but none has a proven solution. Posting here to get help. Thanks